# Broken page rendering on Google Chrome, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, integrated-graphics, rendering

I am using a Dell Latitude E5420 (intel intergrated graphics), windows 10 Home and 4GB of RAM. Google Chrome has some severe rendering issues on some pages and they end up looking like this:

[image: Scrot1]

The only way to see through the black and white blocks which are either square or rectangular but mostly square, is to select the text or image that I want to see. And this is when stuff goes even crazier. Black and white blocks flashing, moving around, appearing and disappearing. Similar behavior is noticed when scrolling up and down.

Now onto fixing the problem

At first I tried to see if this is an issue on chrome or browsers in general. I also tried opera GX for a lighter alternative but behavior was exactly the same. This test might not be accurate as I know that opera is based on chromium.

I checked the chrome settings:

[image: appearance]

[image: performance settings]

[image: system settings]

The only one I could suspect causing problems is the hardware acceleration but it was no use disabling it and waiting for when it might happen again. Plus the laptop is already slow enough.

Then I tried to observe for patterns on what happens before things get wild. I was unable to spot something that looked promising:

- It doesn't matter if I have another 20 tabs open or none (I have quite a few tabs open more often than not)
- It doesn't seem to relate to load and resulting heat but that's difficult to tell since the fan is spinning on second speed frequently, even on idle sometimes. The laptop might need some cleaning
- It happens seemingly randomly. It can happen the second a page loads or a bit later. It also happens sporadically. I can use it a few days or a whole week without encountering it and then encounter it twice in a row
- The pages that this happens are not specific and it doesn't happen on the same page every time

My guess is that the graphics driver has some issues. This might or might not make sense, these things only happen on browsers except only once that some rendering glitches (nowhere near that mess) happened on arduino IDE 1.8.19 but that's about it.

I checked the control panel for more info:

[image: control panel]

It says that intergrated graphics are working but I didn't manage to check it during the glicthy rendering.

On the "details" tab -> problem code it only has "00000000" and nothing else.

On the "drivers" tab I have the ability to rollback and update the driver. But since we're talking about the graphics driver, a wrong move could render the laptop completely unusable. I don't have enough confidence in my limited knowledge on computer drivers to do this kind of things.

Comment: Try to [How to Turn Hardware Acceleration On and Off in Chrome](https://www.howtogeek.com/412738/how-to-turn-hardware-acceleration-on-and-off-in-chrome/).